# Queu-ing build opens up browser

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build

I am building with TFS2017 and VS2017 but when I queue the build inside Visual Studio the browser opens up to the tfs site instead of showing the queue within VS. Is this configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vNext builds can only see the build details through the TFS site, so no ability to configure this.

The old XAML builds opens directly in Visual Studio 2017 and to my knowledge you cannot configure this. VS 2015 had one update where it was changed to the TFS site, but this was reverted in the next update.